# Yii basic read and write file helper

Tags: php, file-io, yii

I was searching for a Yii file helper to make read and write operation easy. But I couldn't find anything and it looks strange to me. Is there any functionality for this in Yii?

Comment: have you tried searching in the [yii extensions directory](http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only CFileHelper in Yii. But that doesn't have support for read and writes. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileHelper

There is a extension called http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cfile/ , which has some relevant methods, that you might need.